# Edit Google Sheets HTML embed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to center align (margin: auto) this html output from Google Sheets ([see link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rju5Wh00NIgMGi7LPRSzBXQ0dUngar_YHrenci_ZUpM/htmlembed?single=true&gid=0&widget=false&chrome=false))? I want to use this output HTML embed version of my google sheet, I just need it centered.

Is it possible to make this change via Google Apps Script perhaps?  Ideally keep the same URL.

Comment: But how do I edit the HTML output from Google side?  This is a Google generated html output not mine

Comment: Hi there, please explain

Comment: I’m actually trying to center the entire table on the middle of the html output page

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML script file, add the following block of code within your  tags:

```
<style>
 body{
   text-align:center;
  }
</style>
```

This should allow the text to be aligned centrally.

Comment: Yes but how do I edit the HTML from Google side? This is a generated output by Google sheets not my HTML. I was hoping to change the generator to include the centering